# increment a variable in Java when every time the space bar is pressed

Tags: java

I have been trying to increment a variable every time the space bar is pressed in Java.

The code I wrote is below but it seems to be wrong as it increments without pressing the key.

```java
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class TestKeyPress {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println(keyPressed(null));
        
    }
    public static int keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int var = 0;
        while (var <6) {
            var ++;
            System.out.println(hi);
        }
        System.out.println("max reached");
        return var;
    }
}
```

Comment: AWT events are emitted by AWT components, like frames. If you want to use KeyListener you have to implement the `KeyListener` interface and then register it with an AWT or Swing component.

Comment: [Java tutorials: How to Write a Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the listener into an event. You cannot expect anything happens when the passed `KeyEvent` is `null`. Moreover, you don't specify anywhere the *space* bar is pressed. You also miss the context to which is the key-press event registered. Is it a console or a desktop application? As long as you use `java.awt.event` I suspect the latter. Here is a minimal sample:

**Java Desktop application using Swing**

```
public static void main(String[] argv)  {

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

        int counter = 0;
 
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
                if (counter < 6) {
                    counter++;
                    System.out.println("hi");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("max reached");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
    jframe.add(textField);
    jframe.setSize(640, 320);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
}
```

**Console application**

In that case, you cannot use anything from the `java.awt.*` or `javax.swing.*` libraries and you have to stick with classes from `java.io.*`.

Comment: hi, thank you for you help. is there any was i can do it only with the console. i tried to change your code a bit but i am getting errors. I'm sorry i didn't mention that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Because when the `keyPressed` called the var variable will be zero, you should declare outside the `keyPressed`.

Also if you want to bind with the progress bar you should implement the listener.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class TestKeyPress {

    private static int var = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(keyPressed(null));
    }

    public static int keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        while (var < 6) {
            var ++;
            System.out.println(hi);
        }
        System.out.println("max reached");
        return var;
    }
}
```